# How to test a form with action redirection using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I added a search bar using a form and an input to my React app, and I would like to check that it redirects to the right page.
I am using react-testing-library and react-router-dom.

Here is my component (simplified):

```js
const SearchBar = () => (
  <form action={'/search'}>
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="search"></input>
  </form>
)
```

So I wrote this test to check that when I type something in the input, I am redirected to the /search page (which happens in my browser). I followed https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/ and came up with this:

```js
  it('redirects to search page', async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    const header = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <SearchBar />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/search">
            <div>this is the search page</div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );

    const searchBar = header.getByPlaceholderText('search');
    fireEvent.change(searchBar, { target: { value: 'myQuery' } });
    fireEvent.submit(searchBar);
    expect(screen.getAllByText('this is the search page')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Unfortunately it fails with the following error:

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: this is the search page. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div>
        <form
          action="/search"
        >
          <input
            name="q"
            placeholder="search"
            type="search"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </body>

      91 |     fireEvent.change(searchBar, { target: { value: 'myQuery' } });
      92 |     fireEvent.submit(searchBar);
    > 93 |     expect(screen.getAllByText('this is the search page')).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                   ^
      94 |   });
      95 | });
      96 |

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:37:19)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:92:38
      at getAllByText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:127:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Header/Header.test.tsx:93:19)
```

From what I understand, I believe that submitting a form does not change the location of my router.

Is there a way to make the test pass without changing my code? Or should I forget relying on the `action` of the `form` and instead implement a custom `onSubmit` property that handles the redirection - which I could more easily test?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form action does not use React Router DOM but instead the [native method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#the_action_attribute).

```
<form action={'/search'}>
```

If you want to use React Router for this, consider using a React `onSubmit` handler. Then your original test should more or less work after integrating with your actual implementation.

```
const SearchBar = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // Prevent default native behavior of submit
    event.preventDefault();
    // Push the new location to React Router DOM
    history.push("/search");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="search"></input>
    </form>
  );
};
```

If you are not looking to change the implementation to use the router, I think a good solution would be to test if the `action` property is correct and not test native behavior, especially since it's hard to test non-router navigation changes in ([example](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2112)) and form submission isn't fully implemented into JSDOM.

```
it('has form action for the search page', () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  const header = render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <SearchBar />
    </Router>
  );

  const searchBar = header.getByPlaceholderText('search');
  expect(searchBar).toHaveAttribute('action', '/search');
});
```

Comment: Wow this answer is really thorough! I finally have to resort to a onSubmit action so I will follow your first recommandation. thanks a lot :)